# Which one HTTP gem should I use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, http, client

I want to create microservice (probably as a gem) and It will be REST client to call external API. I'm new at rails and I am investigating which gem I should use. I checked https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients to verfify most popular gems and I'm reading about them on google. I thought to write a question and ask you about your favourite one. I will call JSON API using token auth. Which one I should use? Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Devise' gem is the most popular gem for Rails with authentication.
These links here will provide you with more details on how to configure Devise to work with a JSON API using token auth:
http://abhionrails.com/ruby/rails/devise/token/based/authentication/api/json/2013/09/01/Devise-with-token-based-authentication-for-API/

[Is this Rails JSON authentication API (using Devise) secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745843/is-this-rails-json-authentication-api-using-devise-secure)