# Are JSON API's that authenticate through header tokens vulnerable to CSRF?

Tags: security, csrf, asp.net-web-api

I was trying to find more information on CSRF vulnerabilities for APIs, and the closes I've found is the question here:

[Are JSON web services vulnerable to CSRF attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008469/are-json-web-services-vulnerable-to-csrf-attacks)

The issue is that even there, they're using browser-based, cookie-controlled sessions.  If you're using an authentication token set in the headers, doesn't that invalidate all CSRF concerns?

A browser can't provide the authentication token / session data, because the browser is never given it!  Javascript is responsible for extracting the token and setting it instead -- and if a hostile user can inject code into your javascript, you've got much worse security vulnerabilities than CSRF to begin with.

Am I missing something?